# Web service functionality generation through wsdl file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

is there any tool that automatically generates web service input, output and specify their data types from wsdl file? maybe in java!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of them. [Apache Axis2 for example.](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html)

Comment: Thanks @Jan Doerrenhaus

Comment: soapui also can help :)